# Javascript How to add string to url

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wonder how to add string at the end of the url in Js.
The url must to be available in a variable, so I can request it.
And I get the inputs from a form.

example:

http://localhost:3000/items/   -> http://localhost:3000/items/55ef09351ee9ce3c272ef8e7

Here's my code:

```
var link = "http://localhost:3000" + input._id.value
link = link.replace('?_id=', '');
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("DELETE", link, false);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
```

With this code I get localhost:3000/items/?_id=55ef09351ee9ce3c272ef8e7
How can I make it without the ?_id= ?

code from program

```
<form onsubmit="submit" action="http://localhost:3000/items/" method="delete" name="del_stuff">
  _id:<br>
  <input type="text" name="_id">
  <br>

  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</form>



<div id="output"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">


var form = function submit(e) {
  // stop the regular form submission
  e.preventDefault();


var link = "http://localhost:3000/items" + encodeURIComponent(input._id.value)
  link = link.replace('?_id=', '');
  // collect the form data while iterating over the inputs
  var data = {};

  for (var i = 0, ii = form.length; i < ii; ++i) {
    var input = form[i];
    if (input.name) {
      data[input.name] = input.value;
    }
  }

  // construct an HTTP request
  alert("http request");
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("DELETE", link, false);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');

  // send the collected data as JSON
 xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));



  xhr.onloadend = function () {
    // done
  };
};

</script>
```

Thx

Comment: Removed MongoDB tag as this question is in no way related to it.

Answer (score 2):

use the `encodeURIComponent` function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

```
var link = "http://localhost:3000" + encodeURIComponent(input._id.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

*I wonder how to add string at the end of the url in Js. The url must to be available in a variable, so I can request it.*

```
location.href += input._id.value;
```

Now how you want to format the url is upto you.

Answer (score 0):

> With this code I get localhost:3000/items/?_id=55ef09351ee9ce3c272ef8e7 How can I make it without the ?_id= ?

Please check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ltmfztmn/), it worked fine!

```
var link = "http://localhost:3000/?_id=55ef09351ee9ce3c272ef8e7"
link = link.replace('?_id=', '');
alert(link);
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you have to modify the .htaccess file. This is how you would define a rule to remove question mark from a URL,

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1%1? [R,L]
```